# Java Soccer Fixture Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write a code that creates a match fixture of soccer league
Like;
`
Half round of the season

1. week
   Team1 - Team2
   Team3 - Team4
2. week
   Team1 - Team3
   Team2 - Team4
3. week
   Team1 - Team4
   Team2- Team3

...
And 2nd half round of the season right opposite
`
I'll get the 2nd half round from the homeT and awayT LinkedLists but before that for 1st half round i've got a problem with shuffle, sometimes getting right results of all weeks but sometimes it stuck before calculating all weeks [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp797.png).[here calculated succesfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e3iF.png)

Here's my code:

```
public void run() {
        System.out.print("Enter team count: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int teamCount = scanner.nextInt();
        LinkedList<String> teams = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < teamCount; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter team name: ");
            teams.add(scanner.next());
        }

        for (String i : teams) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        LinkedList<String> homeT = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<String> awayT = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<String> cloneList = new LinkedList<>();
        int counter = 1;
        boolean afterFirstWeek = false;
        boolean t = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < teamCount - 1; i++) {
            String homeTeam;
            String awayTeam;
            int matchCount = 0;
            String weeksMatches = "";

            cloneList = (LinkedList<String>) teams.clone(); // refresh teams each week

            while (matchCount < teamCount / 2) {
                boolean isContinue = true;
                if (afterFirstWeek) {
                    Collections.shuffle(cloneList);
                    homeTeam = cloneList.peek();
                    cloneList.removeFirst();
                    awayTeam = cloneList.peek();
                    cloneList.removeFirst();

                    for (int j = 0; j < homeT.size(); j++) {
                        if ((homeTeam.equals(homeT.get(j)) && awayTeam.equals(awayT.get(j))) || (awayTeam.equals(awayT.get(j)) && homeTeam.equals(homeT.get(j)))) {
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                        if (homeTeam.equals(awayT.get(j)) && awayTeam.equals(homeT.get(j))) {
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if (isContinue) {
                        homeT.add(homeTeam);
                        awayT.add(awayTeam);
                        weeksMatches += homeTeam + " vs " + awayTeam + "\n";
                        matchCount++;
                        counter++;
                    } else {
                        Collections.shuffle(cloneList);
                        cloneList.add(homeTeam);
                        cloneList.add(awayTeam);
                        Collections.shuffle(cloneList);
                    }
                } else {
                    Collections.shuffle(cloneList);
                    homeTeam = cloneList.peek();
                    cloneList.removeFirst();
                    awayTeam = cloneList.peek();
                    cloneList.removeFirst();

                    homeT.add(homeTeam);
                    awayT.add(awayTeam);
                    weeksMatches += homeTeam + " vs " + awayTeam + "\n";
                    matchCount++;
                    counter++;

                }
                if (!afterFirstWeek && matchCount == teamCount / 2)
                    afterFirstWeek = true;
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(i + 1 + ". week matches");
            System.out.println(weeksMatches);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {

        }
    }
```

I get team count from console then put the team names into team LinkedList, then fixture matches 1st half round of the season, firstly calculate 1st week then give conditions to calculate next weeks. And probably this for loop's first if condition has issue. It calculates correct sometimes, and sometimes doesn't.

```
for (int j = 0; j < homeT.size(); j++) {
                        if ((homeTeam.equals(homeT.get(j)) && awayTeam.equals(awayT.get(j))) || (awayTeam.equals(awayT.get(j)) && homeTeam.equals(homeT.get(j)))) {
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                        if (homeTeam.equals(awayT.get(j)) && awayTeam.equals(homeT.get(j))) {
                            isContinue = false;
                        }
                    }
```